# Find DATETIME by unixtimestamp

Tags: sqlite, datetime

Hi i'm trying to find rows where the unixtimestamp is 0:

```
WHERE datetimeField = datetime(0,'unixepoch','localtime') -> does not work
WHERE datetimeField = datetime(0,'unixepoch','utc') -> does not work
WHERE datetimeField = '1970-01-01T01:00:00' -> works
```

any ideas why no datetime-format works?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing a string comparison [sqlite's "=" is not timestamp-aware, it's comparing two things for equality]. Your datetimeField is presumably being stored as the String '1970-01-01T01:00:00', which sqlite's datetime functions can gracefully deal with, but is still eventually a string because sqlite [doesn't have an intrinsic datetime](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) type

Note that all three of these are *different strings*, and thus won't return true for the equality check:

```
sqlite> select  datetime(0,'unixepoch','localtime');
1969-12-31 16:00:00
sqlite> select datetime(0,'unixepoch','utc');
1970-01-01 08:00:00
sqlite> select '1970-01-01T01:00:00';
1970-01-01T01:00:00
sqlite>
```

To clarify, a simple solution to this problem is to convert everything to another format that you're confident it can be converted to, and is easy to compare. Since you've already brought it up, I quite like epoch seconds. Given your date of one hour after midnight, on the first of January 1970:

```
sqlite> select strftime('%s', '1970-01-01T01:00:00');
3600
sqlite>
```

So from your code:

```
{stuff} WHERE 0 = strftime('%s', datetimeField)
```